# Does not contain a definition for 'CreateObjectSet' and no extension method 'CreateObjectSet'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm using EntityFramwork 6 and I'm getting this error when trying to implement a generic repository pattern:

> DBEntities does not contain a definition for 'CreateObjectSet' and no
>   extension method 'CreateObjectSet'.

Here is the code:

```
    private DBEntities entities = null;
    IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    public GenericRepository(DBEntities _entities)
    {
        entities = _entities;
        _objectSet = entities.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
```

Here is DBEntities' code:

```
 public partial class DBEntities : DbContext
    { ... }
```

Comment: Get yourself a heads-up on the DbContext API. `CreateObjectSet` is part of the deprecated `ObjectContext` API. Today it's `Set<T>()`.

Comment: `CreateObjectSet` is a member of `ObjectContext`.  What is `DBEntities`?  Is that a `DbContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do, this is the correct EF6 way of doing it with DbContext.

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext _context = null;
    private DbSet<T> _entities = null;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```